# Is there a way to create a Bigquery table with data-dependent schema in Google Dataflow?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to create a Bigquery table as part of the dataflow. The examples show passing the schema as TableFieldSchema instance. However, the tableschema I have is data dependent, and hence can at best be created as an element in PCollection<TableFieldSchema>. For example:

```
PCollection<TableRow> quotes = ...;

  quotes.apply(BigQueryIO.Write
      .named("Write")
      .to("my-project:output.output_table")
      .withSchema(schema)
      .withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE)
   .withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED));
```

Here *schema* needs to be a TableFieldSchema, but I have it as PCollection<TableFieldSchema>.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing different values to different BigQuery tables in Apache Beam](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43505534/writing-different-values-to-different-bigquery-tables-in-apache-beam)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We, unfortunately, don't have a built-in API to write to a BigQuery table with a dynamic schema. That said, we are working on improving flexibility in this area. No estimates at this time, but we hope to get this soon.

In the meanwhile, some workarounds have been proposed on other StackOverflow questions:

- [How do I write to BigQuery using a schema computed during Dataflow execution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29440279/how-do-i-write-to-bigquery-using-a-schema-computed-during-dataflow-execution)
- [How do I write to BigQuery a schema computed during execution of the same Dataflow pipeline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30687501/how-do-i-write-to-bigquery-a-schema-computed-during-execution-of-the-same-datafl)

Comment: Sorry to be a noob here. So, I can write a Custom Source, but I would still get a PCollection&lt;TableFieldSchema>, rather than a tablefieldSchema. I guess I am struggling how to write a function something like this:
`public static TableFieldSchema convFn(PCollection<TableFieldSchema>) schColl)`

Comment: I guess I am looking for something similar to Apache Spark's `rdd.collect()`.

Comment: Custom sources/sinks don't support side inputs yet, so it would likely be hard to pass PCollection<TableFieldSchema> and PCollection<YourData> simultaneously. That said, if the schema can be computed within the custom sink, as opposed to being passed to it, that might be viable.